# DataBindingUtil bind layout from include

Tags: android, layout, view, android-inflate

I have such content.xml Layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <view.TouchyWebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/content_view" >
    </view.TouchyWebView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/view_list"
        layout="@layout/fragment_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="596dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_view"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-9dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, container, false);
WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false); // this does'n work
```

And how can I bind fragment_list from include to DataBindingUtil.inflate or DataBindingUtil.bind?

like `DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);` but throw content.xml Layout

Comment: The best and easy solution [here](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/android-databinding) Let me know any issue?

Comment: can i somehow use view.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_list) because he cant cast view to layout?

Comment: You want to use DataBinding for Fragment right?

Comment: Yes, some time ago i had databinding on fragment_list layout like DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false), it was separate xml, but now i need to add additional view before it. I created new xml with new TouchyWebView and include the old fragment_list layout and now I dont know how to bind my old fragment_list layout from include.

Comment: I posted answer below you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DataBinding in for fragment in android, use following way->

Create ->

```
private FragmentYourVideosBinding binding;
private View view;
```

Then use - >

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_your_videos, container, false);
view = binding.getRoot();
return view;
```

To access the FragmentBindinding just type FragmentBinding then you will see your Fragment Binding layout name in dropdownlist. Is described in above link you can read from there.

Firstly wrap your all child layouts by **layout tag** as below. You can copy the code its same as your code.

```
            <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
                <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >


                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <view.TouchyWebView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:id="@+id/content_view" >
                        </view.TouchyWebView>

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/view_list"
                            layout="@layout/fragment_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="596dp"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_view"
                            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-9dp" />
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </layout>
```

Comment: You meen
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, container, false);
WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
view = binding.getRoot();

Comment: To find the id of any layout, TextView, Button or anything else from xml file you have to write -> binding.name_of_layout . No need to write finViewById.

Comment: In content.xml I have two element on the screen TouchyWebView with id (content_view) and included @layout/fragment_list". I cant bind my view = binding.getRoot(); as you written, because it will show only one element - @layout/fragment_list and no @+id/content_view

Comment: Firstly wrap your all layouts by <layout></layout> tag. Its necessary. I also updated my answer you can copy and paste the code.